# CruiseControl publishers issue

Tags: cruisecontrol

Our cruisecontrol system was setup mostly by another employee and I tried to get the e-mails to work. I've got it all working now except the build fixed e-mail only goes to me and not the users that checked in the code.

Here is the publishers part of the config file:

```
<publishers>
    <onfailure>
        <email mailhost="[ourHost]"
       defaultsuffix="[@ourDomain]"
               returnaddress="[myEmailAddress]"
               buildresultsurl="[resultsUrl]"
       spamwhilebroken="false"
       reportsuccess="fixes">
    <map alias="dan" address="[dansRealEmail"/>
        <always address="[myEmail]"/>
    <always address="[managersEmail]"/>
        </email>
    </onfailure>
    <onsuccess>
        <email mailhost="[ourHost]"
        defaultsuffix="[@ourDomain]"
                returnaddress="[myEmail"
                      buildresultsurl="[resultsURL]"
            skipusers="true"
        spamwhilebroken="false">
    <map alias="dan" address="[dansRealEmail]"/>
        <always address="[myEmail]"/>
    </email>
    </onsuccess>
</publishers>
```

If some of the logic seems wrong here, that's because it is. Basically I've tried to do just about everything logical or not, and no matter what the build failed e-mail will go to the users who checked in the code, and the build fixed e-mails will not. Or I'll break it so it doesn't go to anyone. :)

I want to get the cruisecontrol e-mail no matter what, which is the way it is now. I want the manager and users who checked in the code to receive the e-mail on build failed and build fixed. I'm just misunderstanding some of the cruisecontrol logic on how to do this, any direction would be very much appreciated.